How to (Force) Install Specific Version of Python with Pacman (Arch)
After a whole system upgrade, my Python version was bumped up to 3.13.1. I mostly use Python nowadays as a dependency of KaTrain, which needs Python because its UI is based on Kivy.
Currently, Kivy doesn't support Python > 3.13 unfortunately though, so I would like to force Python to go back to 3.10 or something that is supported.
I've been trying to find a way to do it with pacman, but so far I'm very surprised I don't see anything clearcut for it. I've also tried to install Pythong with yay, but, after the install, my current Python version still points to the one from Pacman. I've tried stuff like this with both Pacman and Yay:
yay -Syu python310 

I have KaTrain installed with pipx actually, so I suspect there could be a way of bringing a different Python version from there as well perhaps.

In short, you don't.

I've been trying to find a way to do it with pacman, but so far I'm very surprised I don't see anything clearcut for it

Arch does not package older Python versions. There is only one Python package: python, which is always the latest version (after the mass-rebuild finishes). There are no "versioned" packages for older releases.

I've also tried to install Pythong with yay, but, after the install, my current Python version still points to the one from Pacman. I've tried stuff like this with both Pacman and Yay:
yay -Syu python310 


This installs an older Python, but not an older python – instead, it installs the older Python under a different name (which is probably python3.10 if I were to guess, but you can use pacman -Ql python310 to find out).
Arch does not support replacing /usr/bin/python with an older version, as all system packages (i.e. the python-* packages and Python-based apps) within official Arch repositories are built for the latest version specifically.

Is there no way to have pipx use that python310 installed with Yay to install KaTrain?

I can use this: pipx install katrain --python 3.10.4.
